# PHP Unable to understand colon :

Tags: php

I trying run the following function below

```
function newPlayer($wallet) {
  generate_: {
    $hash=generateHash(32);
  }
  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) goto generate_;
  $alias='Player_';
  $alias_i=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `autoalias_increment` AS `data` FROM `system` LIMIT 1"));
  $alias_i=$alias_i['data'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE `system` SET `autoalias_increment`=`autoalias_increment`+1 LIMIT 1");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`hash`,`alias`,`time_last_active`,`server_seed`) VALUES ('$hash','".$alias.$alias_i."',NOW(),'".generateServerSeed()."')");
  header('Location: ./?unique='.$hash.'# Do Not Share This URL!');
  exit();
}
```

I not sure why my php throw me this error of unexpected : at the line of generate_: { 
Is there anything wrong with this function?

I trying to achieve goto generate_;

how should I correct my code at mysql_num_rows return 0 generateHash(32)

Comment: That portions of code isn't even close to a valid PHP syntax. Why did you think this would work?

Comment: That looks like JS code... and still not valid... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are trying to GOTO (shudders) your syntax is incorrect: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: @JohnConde how should my syntax be if i want to use goto for this function

Comment: Click on the link i provided

Comment: @JohnConde I went into the link and check the Foo Bar example, but its exactly the same as my code wasn't it, or how should I change to achieve same effect.

Comment: Just use a function: `function generate_(){return generateHash(32);}  $hash = generate_();`. EDIT: wrapped function not even needed, just directly call `generateHash()`

Comment: For that matter, just `if ( ... ) { $hash = generateHash(32); }` would do fine.

Comment: The immediate error, by the way, is because `goto` labels have nothing to do with `{`s, so the parser just sees the `{` and doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

`goto` is really not what you should be using here (or, basically, ever).

The simplest implementation is just to put that line in the right place in the flow, since you're only using it in one place anyway:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    $hash = generateHash(32);
}
```

If you think you're going to use it in lots of places, and it might become more complex later, then make it its own function:

```
function generateHashForNewPlayer() {
    return generateHash(32);
}

function newPlayer($wallet) {
    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
        $hash = generateHashForNewPlayer();
    }
    // etc
```

You could maybe also do something with closures, but I can't really imagine why you'd need to here. It would look something like this:

```
function newPlayer($wallet) {
    $dynamic_function = function() {
        return generateHash(32);
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
        $hash = $dynamic_function();
    }
    // etc
```

---

**Edit**: Looking again at your code, I realise that the `goto` here is actually creating a loop (or would be, if it wasn't broken). So what you need to do is replace the `if` with a `while`:

```
while (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    $hash = generateHash(32);
}
```

See [the PHP manual entry for `while`](http://php.net/while).

Answer (score 0):

Well, php isn't using : to fill in variables. You should use this;

```
$generate_ = { $has=generateHas(32); }
```

Would solve your error, not sure what generate_ is in your script. PHP is only using :: to override functions in OOP etc.

Comment: If i change to that, it will not work. Look at line 4